# Error when trying to replace items in a list - Python

Tags: python, list, replace, list-comprehension

I have created a list of lists by using the following code:

```
grid = [['.' for i in range(0,width)] for j in range(0,height)]
```

Later in my program, I want to replace all the `'.'` in the list with random letters in my string `'ABCDEFG...'` I have tried the following code:

```
letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
grid = [i.replace('.', random.choice(letters.upper())) for i in grid]
```

I have gotten this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' has no object 'replace'
```

I looked over the internet and everyone said to use list comprehension with this syntax to replace everything. But unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: Note that you used two `for` statements to create the grid - you will need a similar number to access elements.  You don't need `replace`, modifying your original comprehension should do it.  Replace the `'.'` with your random choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `grid` is a list of lists. Hence, `i` is a list. You can't replace a list, since it's a function based for strings.

You want this:

```
grid2 = [map(lambda x: x.replace('.', random.choice(letters.upper())), i) for i in grid]
```

`map()` will iterate through each list implementing a certain function, `lambda x:`. If you're using Python 3, you'll need to call `list()` around the `map()`, since it returns a generator not a list.

Comment: Ahh makes sense.. I thought it had something to do with the fact that it wasn't just a list.. I was just hoping it would be more simple.